# Core Image Fun House not working?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, core-image

I just found 'Core Image Fun House' in the developer folder.

But When I try to add effects nothing happens.
The effect is listen and I can change the values but the image does not change.

Anyone any idea?

*I work on a Mac OSX Lion MacBook Pro.*